# SQL MIN() returns multiple values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, min

I am using SQL server 2005, querying with Web Developer 2010, and the min function appears to be returning more than one value (for each ID returned, see below).  Ideally I would like it to just return the one for each ID.

```
SELECT     Production.WorksOrderOperations.WorksOrderNumber,
           MIN(Production.WorksOrderOperations.OperationNumber) AS Expr1, 
           Production.Resources.ResourceCode,
           Production.Resources.ResourceDescription,
           Production.WorksOrderExcel_ExcelExport_View.PartNumber,
           Production.WorksOrderOperations.PlannedQuantity,
           Production.WorksOrderOperations.PlannedSetTime, 
           Production.WorksOrderOperations.PlannedRunTime
FROM       Production.WorksOrderOperations
INNER JOIN Production.Resources
           ON Production.WorksOrderOperations.ResourceID = Production.Resources.ResourceID
INNER JOIN Production.WorksOrderExcel_ExcelExport_View
           ON Production.WorksOrderOperations.WorksOrderNumber = Production.WorksOrderExcel_ExcelExport_View.WorksOrderNumber
WHERE      Production.WorksOrderOperations.WorksOrderNumber IN
             ( SELECT   WorksOrderNumber
               FROM     Production.WorksOrderExcel_ExcelExport_View AS WorksOrderExcel_ExcelExport_View_1
               WHERE    (WorksOrderSuffixStatus = 'Proposed'))
           AND Production.Resources.ResourceCode IN ('1303', '1604')
GROUP BY   Production.WorksOrderOperations.WorksOrderNumber,
           Production.Resources.ResourceCode,
           Production.Resources.ResourceDescription,
           Production.WorksOrderExcel_ExcelExport_View.PartNumber,
           Production.WorksOrderOperations.PlannedQuantity,
           Production.WorksOrderOperations.PlannedSetTime,
           Production.WorksOrderOperations.PlannedRunTime
```

If you can get your head around it, I am selecting certain columns from multiple tables where the WorksOrderNumber is also contained within a subquery, and numerous other conditions.

Result set looks a little like this, have blurred out irrelevant data.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UFIp.png (Wouldn't let me embed image).

The highlighted rows are NOT supposed to be there, I cannot explicitly filter them out, as this result set will be updated daily and it is likely to happen with a different record.

I have tried casting and converting the OperationNumber to numerous other data types, varchar type returns '100' instead of the '30'.  Also tried searching search engines, no one seems to have the same problem.

I did not structure the tables (they're horribly normalised), and it is not possible to restructure them.

Any ideas appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to have multiple columns in the WHERE clause before an IN() function? Like so:  WHERE (WorksOrderNumber, OperationNumber) IN (SELECT WorksOrderNumber, OperationNumber FROM table)

Comment: Please note that tags stand alone.  That is, combining `sql` and `server` doesn't mean you're talking about MS SQL Server.  Be sure to select tags with care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MIN` function returns the minimum within the group.
If you want the minimum for each ID you need to get group on just ID.
I assume that by "ID" you are referring to Production.WorksOrderOperations.WorksOrderNumber.

You can add this as a "table" in your SQL:

```
(SELECT Production.WorksOrderOperations.WorksOrderNumber,
       MIN(Production.WorksOrderOperations.OperationNumber) 
  FROM Production.WorksOrderOperations
 GROUP BY  Production.WorksOrderOperations.WorksOrderNumber)
```

Comment: Will declare that as a temporary table yep, thank you, is there any way to do the following in SQL? WHERE Field1+Field2 IN (SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM) etc...

Comment: Bit of a bodge but I ended up declaring two separate tables then using a select clause to query whether the second table contained the values from the first, achieved the intended result set, how future proof it'll be is another matter.  Thank you for guiding me in the right direction though.

Comment: Reply to first comment: If you have another question you should post it as a new question (provided you cannot find the answer by searching the net).