# Sub-query returns multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql

EDIT : it's OK i resolved it. See below for reason.

I have the following SQL subrequest. It says that the subquery returns multiple rows.

```
select MIN(XXXX) 
FROM MyDB.ball b2 
where b2.XXXX > b.XXXX and b2.LLLL=b.LLLL and b2.MMMM=b.MMMM 
and b2.IIII=b.IIII
```

With b = b1 = MyDB.ball in the global request.

in the complete context :

```
if(b.XXXX!='9999', 
(select DATE_FORMAT(Datedepar,'%d/%m/%Y') 
from ball b1 where b1.XXXX=(select MIN(XXXX) 
FROM MyDB.ball b2 where b2.XXXX > b.XXXX and b2.LLLL=b.LLLL 
and b2.MMMM=b.MMMM and b2.IIII=b.IIII)), '')
 as myResult,
```

I already saw this post but I have no group by : [SQL MIN() returns multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13305648/sql-min-returns-multiple-values)

Comment: Do you get the error even when executing just the SELECT? (I.e. without "if(b.XXXX!='9999',...")

Comment: Nop. I tried with the if condition too and it also executes

Comment: So when do you get the error, if it's not with select standalone, and not with if condition?

Comment: Isn't the problem that the *outer* select returns multiple values? I'm not familiar with this dialect of SQL, but try limiting the outer select to one row.

Comment: I mean I tried with the if context but the request is much bigger

Comment: So what gives the error...? And what does not give any error...?

Comment: The error : "subquery returns more than one row". By MySQL Query Browser

Comment: @Luaan : what do you mean by 'outer' ? You mean the Select DATE_FORMAT ?

Comment: @user3651845: That not the "inner" b2 query returns too many rows, but the "outer" b1 query. Try `MIN(DATE_FORMAT(Datedepar,'%d/%m/%Y'))` and see if you still get the error.

Comment: Yes it is. I answered myself ;)

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the reason. It's pretty silly in fact. I had to add another where clause after the subquery. Here is the (ugly) result :

```
select DATE_FORMAT(Datedepar,'%d/%m/%Y')
from FODEGI.ball b1 where b1.XXXX=(select MIN(XXXX)
FROM FODEGI.ball b2 where b2.XXXX > b.XXXX and b2.LLLL=b.LLLL
and b2.MMMM=b.MMMM and b2.IIII=b.IIII) and b1.LLLL=b.LLLL
and b1.MMMM=b.MMMM and b1.IIII=b.IIII), ''
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the outer subquery is returning more than one row, because more than one value matches the minimum.

Why not just use `order by` and `limit`?

```
select DATE_FORMAT(Datedepar, '%d/%m/%Y') 
from ball b1
where b1.XXXX > b.XXXX and
      b1.LLLL = b.LLLL and
      b1.MMMM = b.MMMM and
      b1.IIII = b.IIII
order by b1.XXXX
limit 1;
```